# Delay ajax GET function helps in this case?

Tags: html, ajax, dom, get

I am using the following to save the html of a certain website in a string

```
        function loadajax(dname) {
        $.ajaxSetup({async: false});

        $.get('https://www.example/?param=param1', function(response) {
 var logfile = response;
        //alert(logfile);       
        });

        }
```

The problem is that in the html code there are some codes like `{{sample}}` which seems that there a not loaded yet when the Ajax call is getting the code. When I perform the operations manually I can clearly see HTML code instead of the " {{ }}'s ".

I have already tried `{async: false}`...